# IntelliJ IDEA: how to view .txt files with the features of console: stack trace folding + source links + grep highlighting

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA has powerful features for quick comprehension of its output:

- Console folding of irrelevant lines of stack trace
- Links to source code
- Line highlighting with the [Grep Console plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125)

Is there a plugin or any other way of making IntelliJ have all these features on plain `.txt` files? I am producing a multitude of log .txt files with `Logback` and `SLF4J`.

Here is the closest I got:

- Grep Console enables highlighting of .txt files, but I don't see an option of making it do it by default - the highlighting resets on IntelliJ restart or file contents rewrite.
- I know I can use IDEA's `Analyze Stacktrace...` to bring the .txt file contents to IntelliJ IDEA console, thus enabling all these features, but for that I need to copy-paste the .txt file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a plugin which will let you open a file in the console window. Maybe similar to [this plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/46?pr=idea) but with proper console and not some custom component. It could be pretty easy, or not...

Comment: So I implemented it into Grep Console plugin. Check the new version.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Still, I have to: 1. obtain the file path, 2. open the `Open File in Console` dialog, 3. paste the file path, 4. confirm. If you would add context menu option "open currently active editor in console" I could open the file by pressing one shortcut combination, and THAT would be quadruple awesome ;)

Comment: That would be no problem.